# How to get the parent $(this) value inside a nested function? jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, this

```
$(".first").click(function(){
    item = "hello";
    $(".second").toggle(300);

    $(".second").click(function(){
        item = "goodbye";
    });

    $(this).html(item);

});
```

I am currently using the code above which has a function nested within a function.

When the user clicks on the button `second`, the value of the variable `item` should change from *hello* to *goodbye*. At this point, the original `.first` button that was clicked on should have it's current value changed to the new `item` value.

The problem with the code is that the `html(item)` line of code will get run before the `.second` button is clicked.

I have tried adding that line of code inside of the second (nested) function but it won't work because of the `$(this)` part.

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Synchronous vs asynchronous.

Comment: @dfsq Do you know how I could get this working?

Comment: why can't you move the second click function outside? A bit of HTML would also help with understanding what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tc4kba39/ @A.Lau he can and should

Comment: When the user clicks on a `.second` button, the value of the variable `item` *will* change from 'hello' to 'goodbye', however, nobody will ever know about it because 'goodbye' will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was posted here before by someone but they had deleted it for some reason.

I got it to work through the code below:

```
$(".first").click(function(){
    var me = this;
    item = "hello";
    $(".second").toggle(300);

    $(".second").click(function(){
        item = "goodbye";
        $(me).html(item);
    });

});
```

Comment: It was not correct answer, it was pretty bad answer. You should not use this solution even if it seems working (there are at least 2 problems that are not obvious). Check the demo I posted in comment to the question. You should use separate event handlers and never bind events inside other events. And don't forget `var`.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks for providing a solution! However, that doesn't make use of `$(this)` when it comes to clicking the `.second` button